# How to use Linq to find Min() and Set Min element to 0

Tags: c#, linq

I've the following

```
        List<decimal> Prices = new List<decimal>();
        Prices.Add(999.99M);
        Prices.Add(19.99M);
        Prices.Add(2.75M);
        Prices.Add(9.99M);
        Prices.Add(2.99M);
        Prices.Add(2.99M);
        Prices.Add(99.99M);
```

I can use Linq to get the smallest value by

```
        decimal Min = Prices.Min(r => r);
```

But how can I set the smallest value to 0 in the current list ?

UPDATE

How can I deal with two smallest prices for example 2.99 and 2.99, I'd only want to set 1 to 0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
        List<decimal> Prices = new List<decimal>();
        Prices.Add((decimal)999.99);
        Prices.Add((decimal)19.99);
        Prices.Add((decimal)2.75);
        Prices.Add((decimal)9.99);
        Prices.Add((decimal)2.99);
        Prices.Add((decimal)99.99);

        decimal minimum = Prices.Min();
        Prices = Prices.Select(price => price > minimum ? price : 0).ToList();
```

This will set ALL prices equal to minimal value to 0.

> UPDATE
>
> How can I deal with two smallest prices for example 2.99 and 2.99, I'd only want to set 1 to 0

Well, when this requirement is added to the equation, then @lazyberezovsky's (deleted for a moment, undeleted now) solution was the right one for you:

```
Prices[Prices.IndexOf(Prices.Min())] = 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var prices = new List<decimal> {
     999.99M, 19.99M, 2.75M, 9.99M, 2.99M, 99.99M };

Prices[Prices.IndexOf(Prices.Min())] = 0;
```

If you want to update all min prices:

```
var min = Prices.Min();

for (int i = 0; i < Prices.Count; i++)
    if (Prices[i] == min)
        Prices[i] = 0;
```

NOTES: You don't have to pass selector into `Enumerable.Min()` method, you can declare decimal liters with suffix `M`, and you can use collection initializer to fill list of prices.

Comment: Yes, but more than one price may have the minimum value (that the OP wants to set to 0), and `Prices.IndexOf` only returns one index.

Comment: But as it turns out, your original solution was what the OP actually wanted :) Just the first minimum price. He didn't specify that requirement at first, but this is what he meant, see the updated question.

Comment: @KonradMorawski :)) You never know what OP wants

Answer (score 2):

In LINQ you can do this (it will set all minimal prices to 0)

```
var min = Prices.Min();
Prices = Prices.Select(x=> x==min? 0:x).ToList();
```

Comment: Please move `Prices.Min()` outside the loop.

Comment: You do realize that this will have worst case performance as you will have n^2 iterations of the loop.  Min prices, in max time!